# Is all version of the same dependency jar given in different pom file is needed?

Tags: java, jar, dependencies, pom.xml

In the commons-validator/pom.xml(tomcat\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\lib)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.2</version>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

In the commons-jxpath/pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.0</version>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
```

In the commons-configuration/pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
      <version>1.8.3</version>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
```

But in the lib folder (tomcat\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\lib), only commons-beanutils-1.7.0 version jar is found. Here which version will be used in the dependants

Comment: The dependency versions in the poms are hints for the build tool (maven, gradle) what it should include in the final `.war` file. What you are describing seems to be an expanded `.war` file that the runtime environment (JVM + Tomcat) use to execute the code. At runtime there is no additional downloading of dependencies. If only a `commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar` is present this is the version that is used. That means that maybe some code from `commons-validator` will fail at runtime, because a class or a method it requires is not present.